# How to get User object in Doctrine event subscriber in Zend Expressive

Tags: php, doctrine, mezzio

Based on https://github.com/DamienHarper/DoctrineAuditBundle I'm trying to develop audit module for my Zend Expressive application.
But I don't know how to get the User data (id) within audit logic.

I see that `$user` is passed as request attribute in 
`vendor/zendframework/zend-expressive-authentication/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.php`, but this doesn't make it available via

```
$container->get(\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface::class)->getAttribute(\Zend\Expressive\Authentication\UserInterface::class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read again about the [concept of middleware](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-expressive/v3/getting-started/features/#flow-overview). In short, expressive has a middleware stack and depending on a request, it sends a the request through specific layers of middleware.

In your example the request goes through AuthenticationMiddleware. So if you have this as your pipeline:

```
$app->pipe(AuthenticationMiddleware::class);
$app->pipe(AuditMiddleware::class);
```

The request goes first through the AuthenticationMiddleware, which makes the UserInterface available in the request, and next through the AuditMiddleware.

In your AuditMiddleware and all middlewares after the AuthenticationMiddleware you can access the UserInterface like this:

```
function (ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler)
{
    $user = $request->getAttribute(UserInterface::class);

    // Do stuff here

    return $handler->handle($request);
}
```

So in your case you probably need to write an `AuditMiddleware` that grabs the user from the request after the `AuthenticationMiddleware` and injects it in your Audit module.

Comment: Ah. Somehow I didn't think about attaching EvenSubscriber to Doctrine Manager in the middleware. That works, thank you.